# default values in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have wrriten a vbs macro to automatically insert values from a DDE Excel sheet to a DB table.

The problem, is that some of the cells are empty 
so the query turns out :

```
INSERT INTO `stock_realtime` (`fkstock`, `benefit_month`)
VALUES (77,  '')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `benefit_month` = '',  `created` = NOW();
```

But my sql table contains default values of '0' just for cases like this when the value is empty.

Still it errors `Incorrect integer value:'' for column 'benefit_month' at row 1'`

The other (full) queries work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'' is NOT empty (numeric) value, NULL is.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly setting a value for `benefit_month`. If you don't set a value for a field then the default value will be set.

That would set the default value for `benefit_month`:

```
INSERT INTO `stock_realtime` (`fkstock`)
VALUES (77)
```